# How do I reset a deployments scale to use HPA after scaling down manually?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have to turn off my service in production and turn it on again after a small period (doing a DB migration).

I know I can use `kubectl scale deployment mydeployment --replicas=0`. This services uses a HorizontalPodAutoscaler (HPA) so how would I go about reseting it to scale according to the HPA?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Once you scale deployment back to its original replica count, HPA should get activated back.  is it not happening?

Comment: HPA will not scale from 0, so once you are ready to reactivate your deployment, just run `kubectl scale deployment mydeployment --replicas=1` and HPA will then takeover again.

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal I didn't try it. I was asking so I can know if it's safe to do so. I ended up not taking this route. I needed to turn off the service to stop Kafka consumption while migrating DBs but I ended up adding a flag to enable and disable Kafka consumption

Comment: Did @GariSingh comment helped you to resolve the issue. Refer to the link on [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) which may help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: @FariyaRahmat his comment in addition to the HPA documentation gave me a better understanding of how it all works. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by the @ Gari Singh ,HPA will not scale from 0, so once you are ready to reactivate your deployment, just run kubectl scale deployment mydeployment --replicas=1 and HPA will then takeover again.

In Kubernetes, a HorizontalPodAutoscaler automatically updates a workload resource (such as a Deployment or StatefulSet), with the aim of automatically scaling the workload to match demand.

Horizontal scaling means that the response to increased load is to deploy more Pods. This is different from vertical scaling, which for Kubernetes would mean assigning more resources (for example: memory or CPU) to the Pods that are already running for the workload.

If the load decreases, and the number of Pods is above the configured minimum, the HorizontalPodAutoscaler instructs the workload resource (the Deployment, StatefulSet, or other similar resource) to scale back down.

Refer to this link on [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) for detailed  more information